# FIXED: HTML form submit button with form_type does nothing

Tags: javascript, php, html

<s>So here's a strange one... I've built tons of HTML+PHP forms and never had this issue before - but in this instance, when a user clicks the submit button, it does nothing. In this form, we are just editing details of something specific. I am using `form_type` as my validation method and to post what I am editing to my database. What could I be doing wrong?</s>

Things I have tried **until the issue was fixed**:

- Changing `button` to `input`
- Assigning an ID to the form and tieing that to the button
- Tried to assign a name to the button for validation instead of using a hidden `form_type`
- Using `type="hidden"` rather than `hidden`
- Using a self-closing `/` at the end of the input

**edit-details.php**

```
<?php include 'includes/edit.php'; ?>
...
...
<form method="post">
 <input name="form_type" value="edit_details" hidden>
 ... form stuff ...
 <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">
  <i class="fa fa-check"></i> Update
 </button>
</form>
```

**includes/edit.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['form_type']) AND !empty($_POST['form_type'])){
 if($_POST['form_type'] == 'edit_details') {
  ... everything that posts to database with above form's variables ...
 }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `<button>` try it `<input type="submit">`

Comment: Forgot to mention that I tried tons of other various methods, including that .. it's a real strange issue.

Comment: print $_POST, It will help you to debug

Comment: This works fine at my side: http://codepad.org/w2OQG2kV

Comment: this works fine for me. maybe you should try after putting edit.php's code into same file.

Comment: @DipanwitaKundu The only error I have seems to be with how I am doing my `session_start();` -- but that's something completely different.. all of my other forms in the application work just fine, in the same fashion.

Comment: add type in input field `<input name="form_type" value="edit_details" type="hidden">`

Comment: @SuperUser Still nothing, I'm afraid

Comment: @Darshkhakhkhar Both files are over 800 lines each... thus my truncation

Comment: @Robert Dewitt we can't help you more with only this example, because it seems the above code works fine by it self. The problem is probably something else

Comment: Try to update `<input name="form_type" value="edit_details" hidden>` to `<input name="form_type" value="edit_details" type="hidden">` if you are sure that you are able to reach inside the first `if()` condition

Comment: @RobertDewitt it is also working after putting codes into seprate file. try printing something into else part of if(isset($_POST['form_type']) AND !empty($_POST['form_type'])){}

Comment: Hm... there must be something deeper going on.. sorry I cannot provide more of what's happening. It's probably just me. I'll post an answer when I find out what happened. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that it was something deeper. There was some `JavaScript` messing with my validation at some point, which never caused the button to submit the `POST` command.

Comment: For future readers, this is actually a very common reason forms won't submit, especially if you used a theme and added custom form fields!

Comment: @Nerdi.org That was exactly the situation I was in! Custom theme with who knows what was happening